# ¿como realiza una busqueda con dos o mas palabras en una sola variable en MongoDB?

Tags: nodejs, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoatlas

estoy realizando un filtro de busqueda donde se podra ingresar dos o mas opciones para una variable de busqueda, soy nuevo en mongodb ya realice una busqueda simple con un solo dato en la variable y funciona perfectamente. quiera sabes ¿como se realizaria una busqueda cuando algunas de mis variables contengan un array de varios datos?, la base de datos se encuentra realizada en mongodb. Anexo imagenes y fragmento del codigo, gracias por su ayuda.

Codigo de filtrado de la información:

```
sellerRouter.post('/filterVehiclesWithMongo', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
//aqui declaramos las respuestas
const reponseJson: ResponseModel = new ResponseModel();
let query: any = {};
//aqui declaramos las variables que vamos a recibir
const { minYear, maxYear, minKm, maxKm, minPrice, maxPrice, brand, model, ubication, type_vehicle} = req.body;

//aqui creamos las condiciones para el filtro de los vehiculos y las querys

if (!minYear && !maxYear) {
    query.year = {$gte: 0};
}else if(minYear && !maxYear){
    query.year = {$gte: minYear};
}else if(!minYear && maxYear){
    query.year = {$lte: maxYear};
}else{
    query.year = {$gte: minYear, $lte: maxYear};
}

if (!minKm && !maxKm) {
    query.km = {$gte: 0};
}else if(minKm && !maxKm){
    query.km = {$gte: minKm};
}else if(!minKm && maxKm){
    query.km = {$lte: maxKm};
}else{
    query.km = {$gte: minKm, $lte: maxKm};
}

if (!minPrice && !maxPrice) {
    query.price = {$gte: 0, $ne:null};
}else if(minPrice && !maxPrice){
    query.price = {$gte: minPrice, $ne:null};
}else if(!minPrice && maxPrice){
    query.price = {$lte: maxPrice, $ne:null};
}else{
    query.price = {$gte: minPrice, $lte: maxPrice, een:null};
}

query.city = {$regex: ubication, $options: 'i'};
query.brand = {$regex: brand, $options: 'i'};
query.model = {$regex: model, $options: 'i'};
query.type_vehicle = {$regex: type_vehicle, $options: 'i'};

const vehiclesFiltered = await vehicles.find(query).sort({date:-1});

if (vehiclesFiltered) {

    reponseJson.code = 200;
    reponseJson.message = "success";
    reponseJson.status = true;
    reponseJson.data = vehiclesFiltered;

}else{

    reponseJson.code = 400;
    reponseJson.message = "no existe";
    reponseJson.status = false;

}

res.json(reponseJson);
```

});

[image: Imagen del filtro, por ahora se una radiobuttons para la busqueda, pero se usaran checkbox, para estos datos]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trato de convertir el campo "type_vehicle" en un array si es una sola palabra

```
const typeVehicleArray = Array.isArray(type_vehicle) ? type_vehicle : [type_vehicle];
```

Hago uso del operador $in para buscar documentos cuyo campo "type_vehicle" coincida con alguno de los valores en el array "typeVehicleArray"

```
query.type_vehicle = { $in: typeVehicleArray };
```

```
const vehiclesFiltered = await vehicles.find(query).sort({ date: -1 });
```

Comment: hola julian muchas gracias, el operado o sintaxis $in funciona como la sintaxis IN en mysql cierto?

Comment: en principio si